# Can't choose x86 platform in VS 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010

In VS 2010 i do not have possibility to choose x86 platform. There is always ANY CPU. How can i change this. I need x86 because some dll works only in x86.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open the Platform dropdown and click `<New...>`.  You can choose x86 from the dialog which opens.

Answer (score 2):

If you open the Platform drop list and select NEW, you can choose x86.